# Function with two generic types

Tags: go, generics

I want to write a generic function that looks like this:

```
func Transform(a A) B
```

... where both A and B are generic types.

If I only had a single generic type, I could do like this:

```
func Transform[A SomeType | SomeOtherType](a A) B
```

But how can I also define the B type?

This does not work:

```
func Transform[A SomeType | SomeOtherType][B SomeThirdType](a A) B
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics? It's comma separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you do when you have multiple parameters for a function? You list them separated by *comma*. What do you do when a function has multiple type parameters? Yes, you list them separated by *comma*:

```
func Transform[A SomeType | SomeOtherType, B SomeThirdType](a A) B
```

This is detailed in [Spec: Type parameter declarations:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations)

> ```
> TypeParameters  = "[" TypeParamList [ "," ] "]" .
> ```